# Is there any easy way to print text using zend_pdf?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-pdf

I want to create a PDF file using zend_pdf. But this way seems not efficient at all because I need to define the exact text location :(

```
$page->drawText(""Some text", $x, $y);
```

Is there any easier way to print text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know I don't think that there is an easy way to print a PDF with Zend_Pdf because you have to position everything.

For printing PDF in PHP, I always used [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/) and converted HTML to PDF with great results. Unless you are forced to use Zend_Pdf I think you should avoid it. (I used the 1.11 version so things might change).

Comment: I have written a fairly simple wrapper class that you might find helpful. https://github.com/jamesggordon/Wrap_Pdf